# Get all related field in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am struggling to understand how one-to-many and many-to-many relation works in Django model. My schema looks something like this so far, I am open for suggestions to make it better.

[image]

A many-to-many relation between users and team. Also, there will be schedules that belong to a particular user of a team.

This is how my model looks like so far,

```
class Team(models.Model):
    tid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    pay_rate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BelongsTo(models.Model):
    bid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Question:** I want to get the information of each user, what are their schedules and which team each schedule belongs to. How would I to do it? I have tried `BelongsTo.objects.select_related().all()`, but it is not working for me.

Note: I am open for suggestions, if something is wrong with my schema or model or the approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BelongsTo` is seems like utility table.So

```
BelongsTo.objects.all().values('user', 'team__team_name', 'schedule')
```

Comment: its giving me an error. `Cannot resolve keyword ' team_name' into field. Choices are: belongsto, manager_name, team_name, tid`

Comment: Sorry, typo , remove space in between

Comment: I think it worked!!! :) Let me test it with few other fields before I select it as the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can get related field using `__` (double underscore) like i did for `team__team_name` , `user__username` ,`schedule__date`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks almost right, but I would modify it a little bit. In particular, I will change how `Schedule` is implemented. Instead of having a `sid` in the `User Belongs To` join-table, I would include the user and team in the `Schedule` table as foreign keys.

This is how the Django models should then look like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    # put other fields like password etc. here

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ManyToManyField("User")

class Schedule(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User")
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team")
    date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    pay_rate = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Note the following:

1. You don't need to have a primary key field in the models because Django adds a primary key field called `pk` or `id` automatically.
2. Note the absence of the `User Belongs To` model. Django implements join-tables like `User Belongs To` automatically when you use a ManyToManyField. See the [Django docs on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).
3. You also don't need `on_delete = models.CASCADE` on ForeignKey fields, because this is the default behavior.

To see how to get information about users, teams and schedule from this configuration of models, consult the [Django documentation on making db queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/). It's quite easy.

Comment: It looks good, how would I query out all the schedules for each user? Something like this, `Schedule.objects.select_related().all()`?

Comment: Like this `martin = User.objects.get(username = "martin")` and then `schedules_of_martin = Schedule.objects.filter(user = martin)`. I strongly recommend reading the [Django documentation on making db queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/). It takes just 10 minutes to read and you will be making db queries like a pro after that.